# How to set password to Active Directory account using vbscript and excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I've created a script that will export data from an excel worksheet and create an AD user. Everything works perfectly if I set the password inside the script; but I do not want to place the password in the script, I need it to pull the password from the worksheet. Every time i try to reference the cell that contains the password, i get the error message: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'objUser.SetPassword'   Like I said, I can pull everything else with no problem and create the entire account but cannot get pass the set password error. Line 35 is where is errors out.

```
' Create User Accounts Based on Information in a Spreadsheet
Const ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT = &H6
Const ADS_ACEFLAG_OBJECT_TYPE_PRESENT = &H1
Const CHANGE_PASSWORD_GUID = "{ab721a53-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b}"
Const ADS_RIGHT_DS_CONTROL_ACCESS = &H100

Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000

Const ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND = 3
Const ADS_PROPERTY_DELETE = 4

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
    ("C:\New_users.xlsx")

intRow = 2

Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
    Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://ou=Share Point Users,dc=com")
    Set objUser = objOU.Create _
        ("User", "cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value)
    objUser.GivenName = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value
    objUser.SN = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value
    objuser.displayName = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 4).Value
    objuser.description = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 5).Value
    objuser.mail = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 6).Value
    objuser.userprincipalName = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 7).Value
    objuser.samAccountName = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 8).Value
    objUser.SetInfo

    'Set Users password and enable account
    Set objUser = GetObject _
    ("LDAP://cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value & ",ou=Share Point Users,dc=com")

    objuser.SetPassword = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 9).Value 'this where the error occurs
    objUser.AccountDisabled = False
    objuser.SetInfo

    ' Prevent Users From Changing Their Passwords

    Set objUser = GetObject _
    ("LDAP://cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value & ",ou=Share Point Users,dc=com")
    Set objSD = objUser.Get("ntSecurityDescriptor")
    Set objDACL = objSD.DiscretionaryAcl
    arrTrustees = array("nt authority\self", "EVERYONE")

    For Each strTrustee in arrTrustees
        Set objACE = CreateObject("AccessControlEntry")
        objACE.Trustee = strTrustee
        objACE.AceFlags = 0
        objACE.AceType = ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT
        objACE.Flags = ADS_ACEFLAG_OBJECT_TYPE_PRESENT
        objACE.ObjectType = CHANGE_PASSWORD_GUID
        objACE.AccessMask = ADS_RIGHT_DS_CONTROL_ACCESS
        objDACL.AddAce objACE
    Next

    objSD.DiscretionaryAcl = objDACL
    objUser.Put "nTSecurityDescriptor", objSD
    objUser. SetInfo

    'Set password to never expire

    Set objUser = GetObject _
        ("LDAP://cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value & ",ou=Share Point Users,dc=com")
    intUAC = objUser.Get("userAccountControl")

    If ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD AND intUAC Then
        Wscript.Echo "Already enabled"
    Else
        objUser.Put "userAccountControl", intUAC XOR _
            ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
        objUser.SetInfo
        WScript.Echo "Password never expires is now enabled"
    End If

    ' Add a User to Domain Guest and SharepointUserOnlyGroup
    'Also sets Domain Guest as the primary group

    Set objGroup = GetObject _
        ("LDAP://cn=Domain Guests,cn=Users,dc=com")
    objGroup.GetInfoEx Array("primaryGroupToken"), 0
    intPrimaryGroupToken = objGroup.Get("primaryGroupToken")

    objGroup.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND, _
        "member", Array("cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value & ",ou=Share Point Users,dc=com")
    objGroup.SetInfo
    objUser.Put "primaryGroupID", intPrimaryGroupToken
    objUser.SetInfo

    Set objGroup = GetObject _
        ("LDAP://cn=SharePointOnlyGroup,ou=Groups-Security,dc=com")  
    objGroup.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND, _
        "member", Array("cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value & ",ou=Share Point Users,ou=St. Louis,ou=Sites-US,dc=stl2,dc=mddcpa,dc=com")
    objGroup.SetInfo

    ' Remove a User from Domain Users group
     Set objGroup = GetObject _
       ("LDAP://cn=Domain Users,cn=Users,dc=stl2,dc=mddcpa,dc=com") 

    objGroup.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_DELETE, _
        "member",Array("cn=" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value & ",ou=Share Point Users,dc=com")
    objGroup.SetInfo


    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

objExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Worksheet object to get the cell value.

```
Set oWS = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
' Replace all occurances of "objExcel.Cells(" to "oWS.Cells("
```

For the password setting:

```
objUser.SetPassword("Excel Cell Value here")
```

Comment: @user1905097, `SetPassword` is a method. Not property.